# Errors while running Grunt build for the first time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, build, gruntjs, yeoman

I created an angularJS project using Yeoman

Previewing the app using `grunt serve` works well. The server starts and I can browse my pages successfully.

When executing `grunt build` I am getting

```
Running "cdnify:dist" (cdnify) task
Going through dist/404.html, dist/index.html to update script refs
>> No "cssmin" targets found.
Warning: Task "cssmin" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Which I dont know how to fix, or how to begin. Am I missing some configurations?

Configuration is now:

```
  concat:
  { generated:
   { files:
      [ { dest: '.tmp\\concat\\scripts\\scripts.js',
          src:
           [ '{.tmp,app}\\cdnjs.cloudflare.com\\ajax\\libs\\noUiSlider\\5.0.0\\jquery.nouislider.min.js',
             .
             <MY_LIBRARIES>, 
             .] },
        { dest: '.tmp\\concat\\scripts\\modules.js',
          src:
           [ 'app\\scripts\\app.js',
             .
            <MY_SOURCE_FILES>, 
            . ] } ] } }

  uglify:
  { generated:
   { files:
      [ { dest: 'dist\\scripts\\scripts.js',
          src: [ '.tmp\\concat\\scripts\\scripts.js' ] },
        { dest: 'dist\\scripts\\modules.js',
          src: [ '.tmp\\concat\\scripts\\modules.js' ] } ] } }

  cssmin:
  {}

Running "concurrent:dist" (concurrent) task

Running "imagemin:dist" (imagemin) task
? app/images/yeoman.png (saved 9.06 kB)
Minified 1 image (saved 9.06 kB)

Done, without errors.

Running "svgmin:dist" (svgmin) task

Done, without errors.

Running "compass:dist" (compass) task
directory .tmp/styles/
       create .tmp/styles/bootstrap.css (1.739s)
       create .tmp/styles/main.css (0.129s)
       create .tmp/styles/problem-comprehension.css (0.002s)
       create .tmp/styles/problem-timedword.css (0.002s)
       create .tmp/styles/track-detail.css (0.009s)
    Compilation took 1.894s

Done, without errors.

Running "autoprefixer:dist" (autoprefixer) task
Prefixed file ".tmp/styles/bootstrap.css" created.
Prefixed file ".tmp/styles/main.css" created.
Prefixed file ".tmp/styles/problem-comprehension.css" created.
Prefixed file ".tmp/styles/problem-timedword.css" created.
Prefixed file ".tmp/styles/track-detail.css" created.

Running "concat:generated" (concat) task
File ".tmp\concat\scripts\scripts.js" created.
File ".tmp\concat\scripts\modules.js" created.

Running "ngmin:dist" (ngmin) task
ngminifying .tmp/concat/scripts/modules.js, .tmp/concat/scripts/scripts.js

Running "copy:dist" (copy) task
Created 699 directories, copied 1980 files

Running "cdnify:dist" (cdnify) task
Going through dist/404.html, dist/index.html to update script refs
>> No "cssmin" targets found.
Warning: Task "cssmin" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2014-02-06 19:49:33 UTC)
clean:dist           1.3s  ■■■■■■■■■■■ 8%
useminPrepare:html  169ms  ■■ 1%
concurrent:dist      5.3s  ■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■ 33%
ngmin:dist           2.3s  ■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■ 14%
copy:dist            6.8s  ■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■ 42%
Total 16.1s
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeoman out of the box configuration requires some tweaking. cssmin is part of the build task while it commented out. Since 'usemin' is listed later I just removed it from task.

Answer (score 1):

you need add comments for build css files in your app like this

```
<!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- endbuild -->
<!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Gruntfile.js it also say this at a certain point:

```
// By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care
// of minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not
// wish to use the Usemin blocks.
```

So you leave the block in the HTML or you uncomment in the Gruntfile.js! Took me a while to figure it out since I cleaned up my HTML immediatly, but it works like a charm now!